# Plot count each boxplot at the base of each facet using geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the tally of data informing each boxplot in a facet-wrapped geom_boxplot.
The example below gives the count below each boxplot but I would like to align the counts, ideally just above with the minimum of each facet when scales are set as free.  While the last item gives the counts I don't understand how it decides the y-value for the plotting in each case.

```
    require(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = cyl), outlier.size = 1, outlier.shape = 16,
               show.legend = FALSE, lwd = 0.2) +                                   # Make box plots
  facet_wrap(gear ~ ., nrow = 1, scales = "free") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.min = -Inf, 
               size = 5, colour = "red", hjust = 0)
```

[image: Output from this code]

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `geom_text()`.
You could manually calculate **'just above with the minimum of each facet'** before rendering the boxplot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

give.n = mtcars |>
  mutate(y_label_min = min(mpg), .by=gear) |> # Dplyr 1.1.0
  summarise(
    y_label_min = min(y_label_min),
    n = n(),
    .by = c(gear ,cyl)
  )

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = cyl), outlier.size = 1, outlier.shape = 16,
               show.legend = FALSE, lwd = 0.2) +                                   # Make box plots
  facet_wrap(gear ~ ., nrow = 1, scales = "free")+ 
  geom_text(
    data=give.n,
    aes(label=n,x=cyl, y=y_label_min)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>